# Stepping down as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

Yesterday I sent in my resignation as a volunteer moderator of Sustainable Living. I've always loved moderating this website, but in the last year or so I noticed I was visiting the site much less. Also after almost 9 years as a moderator I feel it's time for other people to take over. My goals have always been to help people with sustainability questions, to learn new things myself and to help get the site out of beta. I think I succeeded in all three.

Thanks to my fellow moderators, past and current; [410 Gone (a.k.a EnergyNumbers)](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/48/410-gone), [Earthliŋ](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/85/earthli%c5%8b), [LShaver](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/3379/lshaver) and [Nic](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/1056/nic).
It's been great working with you. And thanks everyone for the things you taught me and for help building this wonderful resource of knowledge!

Answer (score 3):

#### Thanks THelper for your guidance, contributions, and mentorship!

For those of you who may not be aware, THelper is one of the founding members of the site, and the only one who's still around after [following the initial site proposal](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/badges/66/precognitive).

When I joined a few years back, THelper provided valuable feedback and answers for some of my first questions, such as [this answer](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/6722/3379) providing guidance as I was figuring out how to compost while living in an apartment with no yard.

Later when Nic and I were [elected as moderators](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election/1), THelper was there to help us learn the ropes and provide mentorship.

**I hope we'll still see you around from time to time!**